# Click out of the item in CheckedListBox has impact on last clicked item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `CheckedListBox` with 3 items. I click on first one and checked it, then I click out of the item, but I see that click has an impact on item.

There is a video

https://youtu.be/DnCNGZjxkvM

How to solve this? I would like to get click only if I click on item and not if I don't.

**EDIT (special for @Kieran Devlin )**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                string str = "Item " + i;
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(str);
            }
```

**P.S** There is nothing to add, it is very obvious question, I don't understand how I can produce min reprodusable example. It is very simple I have a checklistbox with 3 items (above) then you click on item checkbox and his state changed, then you click out of the item and his state changing again (it is a problem) user don't expect that he click out of the item and it somehow has impact on item. I don't understand what to reproduce here, sorry...

Comment: Please can you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @KieranDevlin special for you :) Edited my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;`

Comment: @LarsTech check on click is not what I am looking for. Check on click just set if I need to click twice in order to check the item or once. It is not what my quesiton about

Comment: It's not clear what is happening on the screen.  Are you saying those check uncheck events are happening by themselves?

Comment: @LarsTech no, those events happening when I click on the mouse left button, but problem is that my cursor is not located on the item. It is not expectable behavior that user click outside of the item but item somehow get this event and changed his state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to intercept the mouse down:

```
public class CheckedListBoxEx : CheckedListBox
{
  private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
      Point pt = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
      if (this.IndexFromPoint(pt) == -1)
      {
        return;
      }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Comment: The same result

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You mean clicking on the empty space inside the CheckListBox control is still changing the checked status of the selected item?  Shouldn't be possible with this code.  You did replace the CheckedListBox control with this version?

Comment: Here is the video I recorded https://youtu.be/pIXXVZoW360

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko My guess is you are clicking enough to cause a double-click.  Try one click to see if it does it.

Comment: Yeh, you are right. Anyway, weird that checkListBox implemented such way that single click can change checkbox status as well as double click... As far as I see that in order to workaround it some custom implementation should be provided... Strange...